# Resque with God uses IO.popen

Tags: gnu, resque, god

I am under rvm.
I have god.
It starts resque.
Resque job opens an `IO.popen` to the local system program, sends it some text, gets some text back from the stream, analyses it a bit, closes the IO.

So: when I run resque as `rake resque:work` — it's ok, everything works.
When I start resque from god run from user, it works.

Now I have made god working from init.d, made rvm wrapper, start it as sudo... So now the communication with `IO` is somehow broken. Resque failed web-report says

```
Unexpected response format
/home/dakemen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bundler/gems/go_gtp-5cd5a4de65cb/lib/go/gtp.rb:451:in `send_command'
```

I have some other resque jobs, that do not do anything with `IO`. They work.

The gem I use to open `IO` to the local application is

https://github.com/JEG2/go_gtp/blob/master/lib/go/gtp.rb

=========

Experiment:

So, all resque workers are started as sudo. Ok. And the worker refers to `gnugo`.

```
user$ gnugo
GNU Go 3.8 and so on works great

user$ sudo gnugo
sudo: gnugo: command not found (WHY?)

user$ sudo echo $PATH
.......... /usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.
I just don't rely on the PATH, opening an IO, but give full path to the service being run as IO stream.